How to programmatically end a contact on Amazon Connect CCP
I am hosting an Amazon Connect CCP iframe in a webpage.  How can I programmatically intercept an outbound call in the browser and terminate the contact if certain conditions on the webpage are not met?
We have tried hooking into various events documented in https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-streams/blob/master/Documentation.md to no avail.
thanks
.

You need to terminate the agent’s connection.
First, grab the agent’s active contact:
https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-streams/blob/master/Documentation.md#agentgetcontacts
Then, find the agent’s connection on that contact:
https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-streams/blob/master/Documentation.md#contactgetagentconnection
Last, end the connection:
https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-streams/blob/master/Documentation.md#connectiondestroy
Note that this will end the contact but not necessarily the call. If that’s a multi party call (multi contact call) and other agents are participating, the call will proceed with the other agents.

thanks @gamliela, I was calling destroy on the connection object passed in to the contact.onConnecting event, but that did not work.  Getting the active connections and then calling destroy on those did work.

Cool. Note it's not recommended to store connections in local state store (redux etc.). See in the docs: "The Connection API provides action methods (no event subscriptions) which can be called to manipulate the state of a particular connection within a contact. Like contacts, connections come and go. It is good practice not to persist these objects or keep them as internal state. If you need to, store the contactId and connectionId of the connection and make sure that the contact and connection still exist by fetching them in order from the Agent API object before calling methods on them."
